How to plot a clustered heatmap in scatter form using heatmaply
The heatmaply package contains an example of plotting a correlation heatmap in nod_type= scatter. This case uses an external function to get the alignment of the correlation matrix and manually passes it to the point_size_mat parameter. So is there a way to draw the default scatter form heatmap, or is there an alternative way to get information about the matrix of rectangular squares generated by the heatmaply() function that can be passed to parameters such as point_size_mat?
something like the clustered heatmap shown in this image


Hey, could you please make a small reproducible example to help understand what you are after?

the example was added. just replace the tiles in the default heatmap with points with  different sizes present values
